# npm ERR! missing script: start (react.js)

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json

I've searched in previous answers and tried to solve this for many hours but with no success.
I've typed in the terminal `npm create-react-app`, moved to the correct cd, and it gives me this error:

'npm ERR! missing script: start'

And this is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "react-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }

}
```

It doesn't make sense to me. help?

Comment: You have no script named `start` in your package.json file. `npm start` is just a shortcut for `npm run start`, which runs the script named `start` from the package.json file (with the `node_modules/.bin` folder in the path variables)

Comment: Isn't is ```create-react-app``` or have you made just a typo?

Comment: @VipulTyagi Yeah sorry, just a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Your `package.json` is missing a `start` script. It should be something like

```
{
  "name": "react-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start"
  },
}
```

Where `react-scripts start` is the command to start your app.

Also, you ran incorrect command. It should be

```sh
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: Thank you.
I copy pasted it to my .json file, and now I get this error:

Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: C:\Users\User\Code\Coding Projects\ES6 Practicce\JS\project\public

Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you did or what caused that but you're missing scripts in your package which should be generated by `create-react-app`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Ah, got it. You used wrong command:

```
npm react-create-app
```

Which only inited your package.json. You should run:

```
npm create-react-app
```

Comment: exactly I don't understand why my scripts are missing.
I installed npm a very long time ago when I just began coding, should I install it again from blank?

Comment: It was a typo sorry.

Comment: No problem. It happens sometime

Comment: I have changed my post to wiki. So anyone in future will get  help. This type of mistake is done by many and in that case this would help. So, don't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

First, use a code editor to open the folder where you put the react file, and open `package.json`.

Then, add the below code lines. Don't forget ",", before or after it depends on where you put it. Think about how you put properties in an object.

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start"
}
```

Then, save, run `npm start` on your command line or terminal.

Answer (score -2):

Add the following to your package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "react-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }

}
```